# What is infinitary lambda calculus?

Tags: lambda-calculus

I've recently discovered the existence of infinitary lambda calculus, or infinite lambda calculus, and am interested but unclear about some of its properties.

So what is infinitary lambda calculus and how is it different compared to conventional lambda calculus? What are the benefits of infinitary lambda calculus over conventional lambda calculus?

Comment: A few papers mention it in confusing fashion, I just need more straightforward clarity regarding the subject.

Comment: You could cite those papers...

Comment: Irrelevant to this discussion. I'm asking for an explaination from someone already comfortable with infinitary lambda calculus who can explain it in a palatable manner. If I cite the papers you'll say to read the papers, and I don't need someone having skimmed the papers for five minutes telling me what the papers already stated. Also you can Google the papers yourself, making citing them here a moot point.

Comment: I agree with @Rodrigo, knowing how it was first presented to you and what confused you would help to answer. Trust the people who will answer for not just telling you 'read the papers' — and if they do so, it won't be too late to start being unkind.

Answer (score 4):

**What is infinitary λ-calculus?**

In one sentence: it is λ-calculus with (possibly) infinite(ly deep) terms, and (possibly) infinite β-reductions. Notice that finite terms and reductions are also infinitary ones!

If you have done a bit of λ-calculus, you probably already know some infinitary λ-terms: the *Böhm trees*, a notion on infinite normal form introduced by Barendregt. For instance, the Böhm tree of any fix-point combinator $Y$ is $\lambda f.fff\dots$ (an infinite sequence of $f$). The infinitary λ-calculus formalizes this idea that $Y \longrightarrow_{\beta}^{\infty} \lambda f.fff\dots$.

It was first defined in [Kennaway et al. (1997)](https://doi.org/10.1016/S0304-3975(96)00171-5) using a topological definition: infinite terms are limits of Cauchy sequences of finite terms, and the infinitary reduction is defined by sequences of β-reductions enjoying a *strong convergence* property. Later, it was reformulated into an elegant coinductive definition ([Endrullis and Polonsky 2013](https://doi.org/10.4230/LIPIcs.TYPES.2011.16)). If you want a survey on the subject, see Chapter 6 of the recent Barendregt-Manzonetto *Satellite*.

(I keep this answer very short since I don't know exactly what you are expecting, feel free to add comments so that I can precise my answer.)

**How is it different compared to conventional lambda calculus? What are the benefits of infinitary lambda calculus?**

*Normalization*. — Still, the infinitary λ-calculus is not normalizing; for instance, $\Omega$ has no infinitary normal form. But there are more normalizable terms than in the finitary setting (e.g. $Y$).

*Confluence*. — The confluence property is broken. However, introducing a variant of the β-reduction (the β$\bot$-reduction, which reduces all “problematic” terms to a constant $\bot$ in one step) is sufficient to retrieve confluence. (There is a precise definition of “problematic”, see the literature about *meaningless* sets of λ-terms. The precise result is: the infinitary β-reduction *modulo some meaningless set* is confluent, see [Czajka 2020](https://lmcs.episciences.org/6194).)

This variant is also normalizing: in the “general” infinitary λ-calculus, for any term $M$ we have $M \longrightarrow_{\beta\bot}^{\infty} \mathrm{BerT}(M)$ its *Berarducci tree* ([Berarducci 1996](https://doi.org/10.1201/9780203748671-17), a refinement of Böhm trees), which is in normal form. If you're interested in Böhm trees, there is a slightly different infinitary λ-calculus (called *001-infinitary*) where $M \longrightarrow_{\beta\bot}^{\infty} \mathrm{BT}(M)$ for all $M$ (see the seminal paper by Kennaway et al., or [Cerda and Vaux Auclair 2022](https://arxiv.org/abs/2211.05608) for a coinductive presentation).

The main benefit here is to extend the benefits of Böhm trees: give an account of the computational behavior of terms that do not normalize. In very vague words: once you excluded some meaningless programs (like $\Omega$), you obtain programs that do not necessarily terminate but still compute something, and have a meaning (like $Y$). Think of a program computing the decimals of $\pi$: it is not terminating but it has a “limit output”, namely $\pi$.

(About this notion of meaning, Barendregt writes: “It is proposed that [the unsolvable] terms represent the notion of undefined. [...] This class should be considered as the meaningless terms.”)